# Is there a PHP function that does this?

Tags: php, function

I just wrote this function for a project I am working on:

```
function valuesValid()
{
    $argCount = func_num_args();

    for ($i = 0; $i < $argCount; $i++)
    {
        $currentArg = func_get_arg($i);

        if (!isset($currentArg) || empty($currentArg))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

It seems like something that might have been implemented before so I was wondering if that was the case.

Comment: what is the point of this function?

Comment: Makes sure $_POST values being submitted (commonly from an HTML form) are not empty and not null.

Comment: If the intent of this is to force the proper passing of arguments that lack default values, this kind of situation already generates a Warning level error.

Comment: Not one that can take a flexible argument list, like yours. There are functions that can test arrays for the presence of specific values (or non-values), though.

Comment: Note that you can do this `if (isset($a, $b, $c, $d))`, but `empty()` only works with a single argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your function does exactly the same of the && operator to me

```
$value1 = valuesValid($a, $b, $c);

$value2 = $a && $b && $c;

var_dump($value1 === $value2);
```

Comment: Oops, I didn't see the @mario's response :P

Answer (score 1):

This is not a necessary validation, as many input field are meant to be left empty on many forms.

There is no general form of Validation, so there is no general function for validation. You should implement your own logic for that.

Keep in mind that only checking for non-empty values is not a satisfying validation.

Answer (score 0):

If understand it correctly, it checks if the values passed to the function are set correctly, and are not empty.

Well, I think that the simple `func_get_args()` would get all of your values and a `foreach()` would be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You should name your function `values_filled()` rather, if that is its purpose. The `isset()` check within is redundant, only the `empty()` test makes sense. Usually you want to use `strlen` to check for the presence of form fields however.

```
if (values_filled($_POST["field"], $_POST["form"], $_POST["text"])) {
```

As said in the comments you will already get a notice at this point for missing fields. But then the whole if could just be written as:

```
if ($_POST["field"] && $_POST["form"] && $_POST["text"]) {
```